# Use Azure PAT to checkout in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops

I'm trying to use a PAT of my Azure DevOps account to clone with the `checkout` step in Jenkins.

What I did was:

1. Create a PAT in Azure DevOps.
2. Create a new credential of type user/password, in which I entered my username and the PAT
3. Created a Jenkins Pipeline job with the `checkout` step using this credential.

I get an error `authentication failed`

I saw in the [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) how to clone using PAT from the command line, using the `-c http.extraHeader` option. How do you use this in Jenkins?

Is there a way to authenticate using a PAT in Jenkins?

### EDIT

I'm working in an internal network with Azure DevOps on-prem, which is not using HTTPS rather HTTP, i've been told that this may be the reason...

Comment: Can you show the relevant part of your Jenkins checkout step?

Answer (score 1):

Please first check if the PAT was granted Code Read scope.

[image]

Then check if the checkout step was correctly set. I had below in the checkout step in my pipeline. It worked fine for me:

Credential created in Jenkins:
[image]

```
 checkout([
            $class: 'GitSCM', 
            branches: [[name: "*/dev"]],
            userRemoteConfigs: [[
                credentialsId: '54c8d07b-a961-4e98-a189-2566868e9673', 
                url: "https://orgName@dev.azure.com/orgName/ProjectName/_git/RepoName", 
                //refspec:"+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* +refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin-pull/*"]]
          ])
```

Update:

Please check if the IIS Basic Authentication for Azure DevOps on-prem is enabled.

When IIS Basic Authentication is enabled on your windows machine, it prevents you from using personal access tokens (PATs) as an authentication mechanism. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/iis-basic-auth?view=azure-devops).

So please try using your username and password to create jenkins credential.

Comment: I did verify all this, Thanks

Comment: @YoavKlein If you enable IIS Basic Authentication for Azure DevOps on-prem, PATs aren't valid. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/iis-basic-auth?view=azure-devops) . Please try using your username and password to create jenkins credential  instead of PAT.

Comment: @YoavKlein Have you tried using your username and password. How did it go?